# Activate Tape Encryption on Windows Server

Tags: backup, encryption, tape, tapedrive

We use windows to make tape (LTO 8) backups with ltfs and now I want to use the hardware encryption. My problem is I can not find a way to activate it. For Linux I found "stenc" but is there something similar for windows?

I only found backup software which have implemented this feature but I do not want to buy a new software just because of this.

So is there a way to activate tape encryption under windows without to buy a new backup-software? Or is there maybe a package for python or an other language to interact with tapes (and encryption).

Answer (score 0):

This questions is related to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1356368/lto-6-with-hardware-encryption-enabled-using-ltfs-file-system-possible-on-hp-ult) post. You can find Windows-based encryption software written in C++/C.